# How to create border-bottom with Multiple Different Colors?

Tags: css

I'm wondering how to make a `border-bottom` property have different colors, as shown in this image below.

[image: Result I want to Get]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was checking the gradient option but honestly is not a gradient what I want to get.

Comment: Use border-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

***Option 1***

```css
.box {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  height: 5px;
  background: blue;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  height: 5px;
  background: yellow;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  
</div>
```

***Options 2***

Another option is to create an `svg` with 3 rectangles of your preferred colors, and use `border-image` option.

See [w3schools docs](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use border-image with gradient:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  border-bottom:15px solid transparent;
  border-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,pink 30%,red 30%,red 60%,green 0) 200;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `after` to your div and set its background color. Use `linear-gradient` to generate the colors you want;

Also check this [Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

```css
#grad1 {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

#grad1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, orange, yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}


}
```

```html
<div id="grad1">Example</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `::before` instead of `borber-bottom`

```css
.box {
  width:600px;
  height:100px;
  background:#262626;
  position:relative;
}

.box::before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:600px;
  height:30px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, magenta 0px, magenta 6px, red 6px, red 12px, blue 12px, blue 18px, green 18px, green 24px, yellow 24px, yellow 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

for be outside

```css
.box {
  width:600px;
  height:100px;
  background:#262626;
  position:relative;
}

.box::before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-30px; /* same as minus height */
  left:0;
  width:600px;
  height:30px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, magenta 0px, magenta 6px, red 6px, red 12px, blue 12px, blue 18px, green 18px, green 24px, yellow 24px, yellow 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```